# Problem with ESP32 bluetooth

Tags: arduino-ide, bluetooth, esp32

I am trying to connect ESP32 via bluetooth classic to my PC to transfer some data from a sensor.

As a first step, I am simply trying to send some random data over bluetooth serial. The code is at follows:

```
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

int myData[8];
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Opening Serial Connection on COM4");
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32"); //Bluetooth device name
  SerialBT.println("Opening Serial Bluetooth Connection on COM6");

 
}

void loop() {

  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    myData[i] = random(0,500);
  }
  if(Serial.available())
    {
 
     for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    SerialBT.write(myData[i]);
  }
   
     
    }
    delay(20);
}
```

In Windows bluetooth settings, I have paired the ESP32 with windows and connected it. I have set up incoming and outgoing COM ports for bluetooth where incoming port is  COM6 and outgoing port is COM5.

However, when I open arduino serial monitor for COM6, it is empty and no data is being printed. I am using arduino IDE. Furthermore, on COM4, there is nothing printed despite the Serial.println("Opening Serial Connection on COM4"); command which I think should work regardless of bluetooth.

I have tried everything I can think of. I would be grateful if anyone can help me solve this problem as I have been stuck for days